# ffmpeg Both text and text file provided. Please provide only one

Tags: ffmpeg

I have the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -vf "[in]drawtext=fontfile=C:\Windows\Fonts\arial.ttf:fontsize=40:fontcolor=yellow:x=2048/2:y=720/2:textfile='credits.txt':enable='between(t,6,12)' [out]" -c:v libx264 -t 30 -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 scrolling.mp4
```

And ffmpeg throws the error:

> [Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 000002354c44eb00] Both text and text file provided. Please provide only one

I am at a complete loss as to how it thinks I am passing it text, as I define that no where in my command. Any help would be appreciated as to why this error is being thrown.

Also the `-max_muxing_queue_size 1024` is because I get this error without it:

> Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape your fontfile path, because the `:` in "C:\" is an argument separator for the drawtext filter.  Since there's no other "arg=value" pairs, it's trying to use some of the command line as the text.

Depending on your shell and how many levels of parsing this is going through, you may need to modify escaping.

This worked for me:

```
ffmpeg \
-i vid.mp4 \
-vf "[in]drawtext=fontfile='C\\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':
fontsize=40:fontcolor=yellow:
x=2048/2:y=720/2:textfile=credits.txt:
enable='between(t,6,12)'[out]" \
-c:v libx264 \
-t 30 \
-max_muxing_queue_size 1024 \
scrolling.mp4
```

Comment: Thankyou! Sorry it was so trivial, I should have noticed that.. I'm having another issue now where I've taken the command and made "y=720/2" to "y=h-30*t" to make the text scroll. This only performs updates every second - do you know of a way to make it smoother? At the moment it just jumps every second

Comment: @Recessive You should ask that as a new question because it's a whole different issue.