Zsh script using formatted date string in FFMPEG command
In my zsh script, I am receiving a string that represents a Unix epoch, like:
myTimestamp="1719742786"

I want to change that date into a formatted string, and then store it in a variable so it can be used in an upcoming ffmpeg script. I'm doing it this way:
theDate=$(date -u -r "$myTimestamp" "+%b %d, %H:%M:%S")
echo "$theDate"

which prints to my screen what I want:
Jun 30, 06:19:48

but when I try to use this variable in my ffmpeg script, I get errors:
ffmpeg -y -i "$file" -vf \
        "drawtext=text='$theDate':fontcolor=gray:fontsize=$fontSize:x=$width:y=$height:" \
        "$output"

Note that if I change out '$theDate' in the script (to something like '$myTimestamp'), I do not get errors.
What I do get, along with Error initializing filters, is this (possibly important?) error:

Both text and text file provided. Please provide only one

Note I am on MacOS v14.5. The man date mentions The date utility is expected to be compatible with IEEE Std 1003.2 (“POSIX.2”).  With the exception of the -u option, all options are extensions to the standard.
My full script:
#!/bin/zsh
outDir="printed"
width=200
height=650
fontSize=95

for file in initial/*.png; do
    filename=$(basename "$file")
    prefix="${filename%.*}"
    theDate=$(date -u -r "$prefix" "+%b %d, %H:%M:%S")
    output="$outDir/$filename"

    echo "$theDate"

    ffmpeg -y -i "$file" -vf \
    "drawtext=text='$theDate':fontcolor=gray:fontsize=$fontSize:x=$width:y=$height:" \
       "$output"

done
exit


GNU date's option -r expects a file name and not a timestamp. See man date.

Your script can't be both a Bash script and a Zsh script, any more than your question can be in English and Dutch at the same time. Which one is it? Of course, if it's actually a sh script, it is also valid in Bash and (under some circumstances) in Zsh. See also Difference between sh and bash

You have to post here the code that you are using, as @Cyrus mentioned, the date -r expects a file. When executing theDate=$(date -u -r "$myTimestamp" "+%b %d, %H:%M:%S") I get date: 1719742786: No such file or directory

Yes, thank you @tripleee. It is a Zsh script.

And yet, @MarcelPreda, when I take out the -r option in date, I get illegal time format. I have included the full script. The folder initial contains a set of images with names such as 1719742786.png

If you are on MacOS, you don't have GNU date at all (at least, not out of the box). Could you please [edit] to indicate your platform, and perhaps the output of date --help if you are not familiar with the platform differences?

@tripleee - yes, I am on MacOS, and have added that fact the post. And it does appear that -u is non-standard on MacOS.

Assuming that the date ... command works, then the issue could be the fact that in the $theDate string there are : (colons), which are used as field separators for ffmpeg filters input. Either you escape the colons, or use a different character, or you write $theDate in a file like the_date.txt and after that use ffmpeg -y -i "$file" -vf  "drawtext=textfile=the_date.txt:... . I'll choose the last option: write to file and use drawtext=textfile=...

@MarcelPreda - You're right! I escaped the colons, and it works! I didn't want to write to a file, because there are thousands of images that I'm creating with the script. ( Do you want to write that up? )

The issue is not so much that -u is non-standard, but that GNU/Linux commenters assume you have other nonstandard options which are "de facto" standard on their platform.

BTW, you don't need the childprocess for basename. You could simply write filename=$file:t.

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55334636/ffmpeg-both-text-and-text-file-provided-please-provide-only-one

@coco , you said I didn't want to write to a file, because there are thousands of images that I'm creating with the script. If you are not executing ffmpeg commands in parallel you can use the same file, just update the content.

As mentioned in the comment:
The problem is the fact that in the $theDate string there are : (colons), which are used as field separators for ffmpeg filters input.
Either you escape the colons, or use a different character, or you write $theDate in a file like the_date.txt and after that use
ffmpeg -y -i "$file" -vf  "drawtext=textfile=the_date.txt:... "

I'll choose the last option: write to file and use drawtext=textfile=...
If you are not executing ffmpeg commands in parallel, you can reuse the same file.
If you are executing ffmpeg commands in parallel, you have to create unique file names and delete them after ffmpeg command ends, to not leave there thousands of files.

Using an external file seems a lot more fraught than just escaping the silly colons. date +"%b %d, %H\:%M\:%S"
